# Android Sim Tracker code

Tags: android, tracking

Hie..

I am making an app in which I am detecting whether SIM has changed or not..?
On installation of my app I am storing the current SIM serial number in shared preferences.
On boot I have registered a broadcast receiver. In `onReceive()` method I am accessing current SIM serial number and comparing it with the stored one on the time of installation,
Below is my code of receiver :

```
    package com.secuirity.sms;

    import org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.GMailSender;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class BootUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Context context;
    String email;
    String currentSimSerial;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String storedSimSerial = settings.getString("storedSimSerial", null);
        Log.d("Stored Sim Serial::",storedSimSerial);

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        currentSimSerial = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        Log.d("Current Sim Serial","::"+currentSimSerial);
        String trustedNum = settings.getString("cellno", null);
        email = settings.getString("email", null);

        if(currentSimSerial == storedSimSerial){

        }else{
            Log.d("Sim changed","!!!");
            new GmailAsync().execute("");
            String sms = "Sim card has changed, " +
                    "Sim Serial Number of this card is\n"+currentSimSerial+
                    "Network Operator"+tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
            smsMgr.sendTextMessage(trustedNum, null,sms, null, null);
        }

        Intent sms = new Intent(context, SMSReceiver.class);
        sms.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(sms);

        Intent netAvailability = new Intent(context, CheckingNetworkAvailability.class);
        netAvailability.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(netAvailability); 
    }
    public class GmailAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String mail_body = "Sim serial number is "+currentSimSerial;
            String subject = "Your Sim has changed!!!";         
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("securemob.viasms@gmail.com", "smsfun890");
            try {
                sender.sendMail(subject,
                        mail_body+"\nThanks for using Mobile Security App",
                        "securemob.viasms@gmail.com",
                        email,null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("Mail","Sent");
        }
    }
}
```

But Its not working.... :(:(:(
I have the following permissions READ_PHONE_STATE" and "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

Comment: Ohh Sorry.....Its Not working...........Dont know Why.... :(

Comment: and what is not working?

Comment: *'It's not working'*... Doesn't help us much either. Please describe what is not working, do you get an error, is the code not activated, ... Furthermore, try to give a simple example showing your problem. Do not just put all your code here and ask for a fix!

Comment: Can you give an indication as to what is wrong? print the log cat for example

Comment: On Boot up I am not getting any message or mail that your sim has changed........

Comment: @KevinBradshaw When cell reboots I dont get anything in log cat. But it works as i am able to start those two broadcast receivers.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see anything wrong in your code, but the first thing I would check is that you have the permission to read the SIM card set in the Manifest.

Comment: I now see you were about to list your permissions. did you just get tired of typing or something?

Comment: I have the following permissions : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: Lol....nothing like that I am not lazy in typing I love ctrl+c and ctrl+v, actually it was not showing.....

Comment: k, your going to have to be a little clearer in what you need help with. So, when you boot up the app, it does not crash? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: When you say you get nothing in Log Cat when you boot.. how about the output from these lines, Log.d("Stored Sim Serial::",storedSimSerial);
        Log.d("Current Sim Serial","::"+currentSimSerial); Do you have any output from them?

Comment: No it does not crash.....And I am expecting is...when I am changing SIM card and rebooting....It must send a message from new sim card and mail me the same.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have written those two statements for getting flow of code, but getting nothing in Log cat...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20512/discussion-between-kevin-bradshaw-and-caution-continues)

Answer (score 0):

Hie Guys I got the solution of BOOT UP Receiver....
When android mobile boots then this event is broadcasts to every app, But app those are installed in the internal memory responds soon as compared to the app stored on SD card.
Hence solution was

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

In manifest file as manifest attribute.